# imaplib - works on pc but not on server?

Tags: python, imaplib

```
import imaplib
M=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
```

when run on my pc it works and alls fine, but on server it returns: `'module' object has no attribute 'IMAP4_SSL'`

well this module clearly needs that attribute.
any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMAP4_SSL is only present if Python's [ssl module](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl) is available (you can test with `import ssl`). Try upgrading your server's python version, and/or installing the ssl module.

Comment: i tryed uploading ssl.py to the folder, got a diffrent error so i uploaded the entire lib folder from my pc to the server, now i get a blank page...

Comment: @galtzhayek ssl.py is just a Python wrapper for the native module. I'm afraid you'll need that too. You should **not** manually upload stdlib modules as these will not be kept in sync with the interpreter, and all kinds of strange things can happen. Remove them, and update Python on the server via your package management system.

Comment: @galtzhayek Oh, then remove all uploaded stdlib files, and write a minimal file `include ssl` (and the one in this question). If this raises an error, contact your hosting provider and let him know you need the ssl module.